# Python - How to validate tkinter entry field

Tags: python, sqlite, validation, tkinter

In my program I have a sqlite database where data is appended to through entry widgets in a tkinter gui. I'd like it so data is only appended to the database after it is validated, as there is currently no validation.

For example, in my function below which appends a customerID, forename, surname, address and phone number to the customer table in my database. I would like it so the customerID entry accepts integers only, forename, surname and address to be NOT NULL and phoneNumberEntry to accepts integers only as well.

I have seen people use the validatecommand but I don't think I would be able to implement that as I am already using a command to append the data to the database.

```
def appendToCustomerTableEntry(event):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Add to customer table")

    Label(top, text = "customerID: ").grid(sticky = E)

    customerIDEntry = Entry(top)
    customerIDEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    Label(top, text = "Forename: ").grid(row = 1, sticky = E)

    customerForenameEntry = Entry(top)
    customerForenameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    Label(top, text = "Surname: ").grid(row = 2, sticky = E)

    customerSurnameEntry = Entry(top)
    customerSurnameEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    Label(top, text = "Address: ").grid(row = 3, sticky = E)

    customerAddressEntry = Entry(top)
    customerAddressEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    Label(top, text = "Phone Number: ").grid(row = 4, sticky = E)

    customerPhoneNumberEntry = Entry(top)
    customerPhoneNumberEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    exitButton = Button(top, text = "Exit", command = top.destroy)
    exitButton.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W)

    appendButton = Button(top, text = "Append", command =   lambda:appendToCustomerTable
                  (customerIDEntry.get(), customerForenameEntry.get(), customerSurnameEntry.get(),
                   customerAddressEntry.get(), customerPhoneNumberEntry.get()))
    appendButton.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = E)


def appendToCustomerTable(customerID, Forename, Surname, Address, TelephoneNumber):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO customerTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (customerID, Forename, Surname, Address, TelephoneNumber ))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You wrote: _I have seen people use the validatecommand but I don't think I would be able to implement that as I am already using a command to append the data to the database._ what do you mean by that? The use of `validatecommand` is completely unrelated to how you use the data later. It is simply a mechanism to prevent illegal input (such as letters in an integer field).

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah I have figured something out now. I was just a bit confused earlier so just rushed into making this post. Now I have got a way to only be able to accept integers so that part of the problem is solved, I just need to figure out the rest of the validation

Comment: It seems like the answer to your question is to simply create a function that takes all of the inputs and validates them, and then to call that function before inserting the data in the database. What are you asking for that is different than that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a question of sql sanitation, or a python programming one?

If sql sanitation, you need to figure out what sql strings or characters to reject, there might also be libraries that do this.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Programaticly one would run if statements, changing the order of opperation and use string replacment.
http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

In your code it seems that your thing to watch for is someone trying to post code trough your fields. Look at the links spechially the last one.

Answer (score -1):

firsty try "[dont repeat your self](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself)"

```
# you can declare here the input type of your argument default and the type of them 
def build(ui_title = [], int_arg = 0):
    # on top you can also assert the input
    # continue only if ui_title is True else give a AssertionError 
    assert (ui_title), "list is empty!!!"

    # lets check int_arg for int
    assert (int_arg==int), "{0} except int get {1}".format(int_arg ,type(int_arg))

    for row,text in enumerate(ui_title):
        Label(top, text = str(text)).grid(sticky = E)
        customerIDEntry = Entry(top)
        customerIDEntry.grid(row = int(row), column = 1)
        if text=="Exit":
            exitButton = Button(top, text = str(text), command = top.destroy)
            exitButton.grid(row = int(row), column = 2, sticky = W)

ui_title = ["customerID", "Forename: ", "Surname: ", "Address: ", "Phone Number: ", "Exit"]
build(ui_title) # will work
build(ui_title, int_arg = "Hallo") # will not work, because int_arg get string and the build method will raise a AssertionError
```

Comment: please give a feedback why vote Downing,  not really helpful for the future readers and me incl........http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: this doesn't answer the question that was asked. The question is about how to validate inputs and this code won't validate data that is entered by the user in the Entry widgets.

Comment: This code seems to be checking the value before the user has a chance to enter any data.